# conectar aplicacion android con dispositivo wifi sin internet

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi

hice una aplicacion para android usando android studio y lenguaje kotlin, la aplicacion se comunica por wifi a un dispotivo esp8266 que tiene una ip local 192.168.1.1, funciona todo perfecto, pero debo apagar la conexion movil (3g/4g) para que se pueda establecer la comunicacion, hay alguna forma de que mi aplicacion solo pueda conectarse usando la red de wifi especifica mientras el resto del dispositivo no pierda la conexion a internet?

busque varios ejemplos que no funcionaron
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492136/force-android-to-use-wifi-network-with-no-internet
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653126/send-request-over-wifi-without-connection-even-if-mobile-data-is-on-with-conn

Comment: **hay alguna forma de que mi aplicacion solo pueda conectarse usando la red de wifi especifica mientras el resto del dispositivo no pierda la conexion a internet?** La respuesta es: NO. El dispositivo usará Wi-Fi para Internet, siempre que esté activado y conectado a un punto de acceso, a menos que tu dispositivo tenga una configuración especial mediante un firmware personalizado (y no estoy seguro de que eso sea posible). Mi sugerencia: usa algún tipo de API que se comunique con el equipo de tu red local y te permita conexión desde Internet.

Comment: No entiendo con exactitud cuál es el problema ni qué quieres hacer con esto. ¿Reinventar la rueda quizá? Por ejemplo,.con Workmanager tú puedes especificar restricciones del tipo: *Haz tal tarea solamente cuando haya conexión Wi-Fi*. ¿Eso no basta para tu caso?